The light doesn't turn on. Got a brand new light fixture and that also doesn't work. I tried new light bulbs
I need a help on electrical wire problem.
There are a black, a white and a naked copper wires. When I connect the light fixture to it, it does not turn on. When I use the voltage meter to check the voltage and I touch neutral and the black wire I see 110 volt reading. But when I try the other white wire with the neutral wire than there is no voltage on the voltmeter.
Am not sure if that's expected.
Now I installed a fixture. I connected the black wire from the fixture to black, white to white and the naked copper wire to green wire.
what could be the problem?

Neutral (white) should be at or near ground potential, so that's expected. Can't say what's wrong with your setup without photos. How was the old fixture hooked up, and did it work before you disconnected it?

What's the wiring look like at the switch?

Need a picture. Your description of whites and neutrals is confusing.
